# Import and edit AdWords cost data

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads, cost

I am trying to follow the instructions at [this Analytics help page](https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1034150), and I cannot find the "Apply cost sources" box required in step 7. Has this been moved? Is it still necessary to link my Analytics and AdWords accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's been renamed. Click on Admin at the top, and then look for Custom Definitions, where you can upload this cost data.

Google suggests a better way to do this using the Adwords interface by [Linking the Analytics Account and Adwords Account](https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1033961&ctx=cb&src=cb&cbid=-1wv2fuq5d5evf&cbrank=0)

I did try this with my two Adwords accounts and single Analytics account, and it works fine.

Comment: You led me in the right direction, but Custom Definitions should not be used for importing AdWords data according to [this page](https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&utm_id=ad&answer=2803329), which points to the instructions for [Linking/Unlinking Analytics Accounts and AdWords Accounts](https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1033961). Feel free to edit the answer and I will accept it.